# Averaging amount spent per transaction over a month up to this transaction

Tags: sql, sas, aggregate, proc

I have a class project data and am working on calculating the averaging amount spent for the past 30 days for each transaction **up to this transaction**.

for example, I have a transaction happen on jun 24 2014, I want to find total amount spent with the account for the past 30 days prior to this transaction (may 24-jun 24) and divided it by the # of transactions in this time frame. I need to do this for each transaction.

the data looks like alltran:

```
obs  tran_date  tran_amt  mechr_cate_cd
1    05/04/14   5.32      4633
2    05/06/14   8.97      5846
3    06/02/14   10.13     7996
```

I want the output to look like

```
obs  tran_date  tran_amt  mechr_cate_cd  avg_amt30
1    05/04/14   5.32      4633           5.32
2    05/06/14   8.97      5846           7.15
3    06/02/14   10.13     7996           8.14
```

I am thinking of using correlated subquery in proc sql:

```
proc sql;
create table sub as
select  tran_date tran_amt
from alltran;
run;

proc sql;
select * from alltran a
      where exists
                  (select avg(tran_amt) as avg_amt30 from sub b
                where a.tran_date-30<=b.tran_date<=a.tran_date);
run;
```

I haven't got a chance to test it yet, but this is my idea, thank you so much!!

Comment: Of course there are ways to do it but you should show us what you have so far yourself first so you can be guided from there. Stack Overflow is not a code on demand service; we help you with your code, not write if for you. Please read [help], [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you are about to, please don't paste code into the comments section, just edit your original question with the new info. (and remember to precede all lines with 4 spaces or highlight pasted code and hit the formatting button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are a lot of different ways you can take care of this, but I like where you are going using proc SQL. I think joins are easier to read than "where exists", so that's what I used in my example.

```
data alltran;
        infile datalines ;
        input obs tran_date tran_amt mechr_cate_cd;
        informat tran_date mmddyy10.; format tran_date mmddyy10.;
        datalines ;
        1    05/04/14   5.32      4633
        2    05/06/14   8.97      5846
        3    06/02/14   10.13     7996
        ;
    run;

proc sql;
    create table alltran_duped as 
    Select a.* , b.tran_amt as Cumulative_tran_amt
    from alltran a 
        left join alltran b
            on b.tran_date <=  a.tran_date <= b.tran_date + 30;

    create table alltran2 as
    select obs, tran_date, tran_amt, mechr_cate_cd, avg(Cumulative_tran_amt) as avg_amt30
    from alltran_duped
    group by obs, tran_date, tran_amt, mechr_cate_cd;
quit;
```

The above proc sql steps do the following:
1) Left join the data back to itself where the tran_date from the joining table is 30 or fewer days from the original record. Records are duplicated if there are multiple records in the prior 30 days.

2) Group down on your original 4 columns and take the average tran_amt values that joined in on step 1. This all could have been done in one step, but I think splitting it up makes the code easier to read.

There are other ways to solve this problem, but I personally think using proc sql is simpler and easier to check (especially if your code is audited by other SQL users).

Hope this helps!